# Unable to open camera flash during call

Tags: android, flash, camera

I am trying to build an app where camera flash will happen in call and sms incoming activity. But the camera flash is not opening during call...i have written simple program.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    .....
    ....

    public static class AlertHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("===inside oneceive");
            boolean incomingCall = false;
            Parameters alertParams;
                Camera alertCamera;
                String callState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (null != callState && callState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    incomingCall = true;
                }
                System.out.println("===incomingCall =="+incomingCall);

                if(incomingCall){
                    System.out.println("OPENING CAMERA...");
                    alertCamera = Camera.open();
                    alertParams = alertCamera.getParameters();
                    alertParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    alertCamera.setParameters(alertParams);
                    alertCamera.startPreview();
                }                   

                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting the sysout OPENING CAMERA well, but now flash.
please help with some code fix. No error in logcat.

In play store lot of this app is present, how they work?

Comment: You need to have a thread & while loop which will handle blinking on flashlight

Comment: I don't want blinking..just open the flash during incoming call...

Answer (score 1):

Use this its working

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static Camera camera;
// flag to detect flash is on or off
private static boolean isLighOn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camera = Camera.open();

}

public static void toggle() {

    if (isLighOn) {

        Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isLighOn = false;

    } else {

        Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();
        isLighOn = true;

    }

}

}

public class AlertHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

boolean incomingCall = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String callState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (null != callState
            && callState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        incomingCall = true;

    }

    if (incomingCall) {
        MainActivity.toggle();
    } else {
        MainActivity.toggle();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: hi sandeep, I just break down my methods as ur suggestion..still it is not opening flash...i have debugged, getting proper sysout at turn on and turn off methods, but not opening flash during call.. :(

Comment: Have you added these permissions  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Comment: yes...they are present...permission are there...also the receiver intent in manifest...

Comment: You can download the code from here  http://www.4shared.com/zip/JftADHOece/Demo.html

Comment: I will try and let u know...but not understanding difference between creating seperate methods and call them and writing all codes in in a sequencial manner... :(